# Gradle buildSrc dependency in secondary module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, groovy

I have an Android Library project that needs an autogenerated class. This class is generated during build time with a Groovy script placed in the buildSrc directory of the Library project. This is working fine by itself.

Then I have an app project that is using that library, so I open Android Studio with two modules: the app and the library. In this case, the build.gradle in the library is not able to find the Groovy class in the buildSrc directory.

Here's my current directory structure.

```
|-- app-module (main module)
    |-- /* application code and resources */
    |-- build.gradle
|-- library-module
    |-- buildSrc
        |-- CodeGenerator.groovy /* within its package */
        |-- build.gradle
    |-- build.gradle /* depends on CodeGenerator.groovy */
```

The only way I found for this to work, is to copy the entire buildSrc dir from the library into the app.

Is there another way I can add the Groovy build dependency without copying the entire thing into the main module?

Comment: I have a similar problem and I've created a public github to show how it fails. If you do `gradle build` in the `myLib` project everything clears, but if you do `gradle build` on the root project it doesn't work for the reasons described above. Help would be appreciated!

You can checkout the project via `git clone https://github.com/mikesol/cradle-multi-project-buildsrc.git`

Comment: Hey @mikesol, were you able to get this working?

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to use the `dependOn` marker on gradle task?

```
task taskX << {
  println 'taskX'
}

task taskY << {
  println 'taskY'
}

taskX.dependsOn taskY
```

More information can be found here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html SubChapter 17.4

Comment: It is not a task problem. The tasks are executing fine. The problem I'm having occurs when I open Android Studio as a multi-project (one being the app, and one being the library). Since the buildSrc directory can only exist in the main module (according to the documentation), the build.gradle in the Library cannot find the dependency of the Groovy class (because it's placed in the Library project instead of in the app project).

Comment: @anavarroma I have the same problem